# jena.shared.JenaException: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: trainUnion.nt

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, jena

My code is very simple, I just want to run a test example but it gives exception as stated in the title.

I have tried to solve it but can't figure it out, can anyone help with this?

```
public  static void main(String args[]){

    Model model=ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    model.read("trainUnion.nt");

    String str="PREFIX syntax:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"+
    " select ?type"+
    " where {?x syntax:type ?type}";

    Query query=QueryFactory.create(str);

    QueryExecution queryExecution=QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);

    ResultSet rs=queryExecution.execSelect();

    ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, rs);
}
```

Comment: Looks like quite an old version of Jena.  The latest Apache release is 3.0.0.  See http://jena.apache.org/download/

Comment: That's it,thank you a lot!~

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to update Jena, as @AndyS said in comment.  Question should perhaps be deleted or closed ... or at least marked as answered.